# How to set graphql data using react hooks in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

I have a component and I am trying to get data from graphql service (https://rickandmortyapi.com) using apollo, it comes okay, but I can't set the data using react hooks:

```
const [characters, setCharacters] = useState<Character[]>([]);

const {data, error, loading, refetch} = useCharactersListQuery({
    variables: {name: String(search)},
    onCompleted: (data)=>{
        //here I can see data very well
        console.log(data.characters!)
        //this line gives me an ERROR
        setCharacters(data.characters!.results!)
    }
});
```

The error occurs when I am trying to set data using setCharacters method

> TS2345: Argument of type 'Maybe<{ __typename?: "Character" |
>   undefined; } & Pick>[]' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.   Type
>   'Maybe<{ __typename?: "Character" | undefined; } & Pick>[]' is not assignable to type 'Character[]'.
>       Type 'Maybe<{ __typename?: "Character" | undefined; } & Pick>' is not assignable to type
>   'Character'.       Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Character'.

My large graphql.tsx file with all types

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ApolloReactCommon from '@apollo/react-common';
import * as ApolloReactComponents from '@apollo/react-components';
import * as ApolloReactHoc from '@apollo/react-hoc';
import * as ApolloReactHooks from '@apollo/react-hooks';
export type Maybe<T> = T | null;
export type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
/** All built-in and custom scalars, mapped to their actual values */
export type Scalars = {
  ID: string;
  String: string;
  Boolean: boolean;
  Int: number;
  Float: number;
  /** The `Upload` scalar type represents a file upload. */
  Upload: any;
};

export type Query = {
   __typename?: 'Query';
  /** Get a specific character by ID */
  character?: Maybe<Character>;
  /** Get the list of all characters */
  characters?: Maybe<Characters>;
  /** Get a specific locations by ID */
  location?: Maybe<Location>;
  /** Get the list of all locations */
  locations?: Maybe<Locations>;
  /** Get a specific episode by ID */
  episode?: Maybe<Episode>;
  /** Get the list of all episodes */
  episodes?: Maybe<Episodes>;
};


export type QueryCharacterArgs = {
  id?: Maybe<Scalars['ID']>;
};


export type QueryCharactersArgs = {
  page?: Maybe<Scalars['Int']>;
  filter?: Maybe<FilterCharacter>;
};


export type QueryLocationArgs = {
  id?: Maybe<Scalars['ID']>;
};


export type QueryLocationsArgs = {
  page?: Maybe<Scalars['Int']>;
  filter?: Maybe<FilterLocation>;
};


export type QueryEpisodeArgs = {
  id?: Maybe<Scalars['ID']>;
};


export type QueryEpisodesArgs = {
  page?: Maybe<Scalars['Int']>;
  filter?: Maybe<FilterEpisode>;
};

export type Character = {
   __typename?: 'Character';
  /** The id of the character. */
  id?: Maybe<Scalars['ID']>;
  /** The name of the character. */
  name?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  /** The status of the character ('Alive', 'Dead' or 'unknown'). */
  status?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  /** The species of the character. */
  species?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  /** The type or subspecies of the character. */
  type?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  /** The gender of the character ('Female', 'Male', 'Genderless' or 'unknown'). */
  gender?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  /** The character's origin location */
  origin?: Maybe<Location>;
  /** The character's last known location */
  location?: Maybe<Location>;
  /**
   * Link to the character's image.
   * All images are 300x300px and most are medium shots or portraits since they are intended to be used as avatars.
   */
  image?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  /** Episodes in which this character appeared. */
  episode?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<Episode>>>;
  /** Time at which the character was created in the database. */
  created?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
};

export type Location = {
   __typename?: 'Location';
  /** The id of the location. */
  id?: Maybe<Scalars['ID']>;
  /** The name of the location. */
  name?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  /** The type of the location. */
  type?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  /** The dimension in which the location is located. */
  dimension?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  /** List of characters who have been last seen in the location. */
  residents?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<Character>>>;
  /** Time at which the location was created in the database. */
  created?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
};

export type Episode = {
   __typename?: 'Episode';
  /** The id of the episode. */
  id?: Maybe<Scalars['ID']>;
  /** The name of the episode. */
  name?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  /** The air date of the episode. */
  air_date?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  /** The code of the episode. */
  episode?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  /** List of characters who have been seen in the episode. */
  characters?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<Character>>>;
  /** Time at which the episode was created in the database. */
  created?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
};

export type FilterCharacter = {
  name?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  status?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  species?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  type?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  gender?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
};

export type Characters = {
   __typename?: 'Characters';
  info?: Maybe<Info>;
  results?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<Character>>>;
};

export type Info = {
   __typename?: 'Info';
  /** The length of the response. */
  count?: Maybe<Scalars['Int']>;
  /** The amount of pages. */
  pages?: Maybe<Scalars['Int']>;
  /** Number of the next page (if it exists) */
  next?: Maybe<Scalars['Int']>;
  /** Number of the previous page (if it exists) */
  prev?: Maybe<Scalars['Int']>;
};

export type FilterLocation = {
  name?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  type?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  dimension?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
};

export type Locations = {
   __typename?: 'Locations';
  info?: Maybe<Info>;
  results?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<Location>>>;
};

export type FilterEpisode = {
  name?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  episode?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
};

export type Episodes = {
   __typename?: 'Episodes';
  info?: Maybe<Info>;
  results?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<Episode>>>;
};

export enum CacheControlScope {
  Public = 'PUBLIC',
  Private = 'PRIVATE'
}


export type CharactersListQueryVariables = {
  name?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
};


export type CharactersListQuery = (
  { __typename?: 'Query' }
  & { characters?: Maybe<(
    { __typename?: 'Characters' }
    & { info?: Maybe<(
      { __typename?: 'Info' }
      & Pick<Info, 'count'>
    )>, results?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<(
      { __typename?: 'Character' }
      & Pick<Character, 'id' | 'name' | 'image'>
    )>>> }
  )> }
);


export const CharactersListDocument = gql`
    query charactersList($name: String) {
  characters(page: 1, filter: {name: $name}) {
    info {
      count
    }
    results {
      id
      name
      image
    }
  }
}
    `;
export type CharactersListComponentProps = Omit<ApolloReactComponents.QueryComponentOptions<CharactersListQuery, CharactersListQueryVariables>, 'query'>;

    export const CharactersListComponent = (props: CharactersListComponentProps) => (
      <ApolloReactComponents.Query<CharactersListQuery, CharactersListQueryVariables> query={CharactersListDocument} {...props} />
    );

export type CharactersListProps<TChildProps = {}, TDataName extends string = 'data'> = {
      [key in TDataName]: ApolloReactHoc.DataValue<CharactersListQuery, CharactersListQueryVariables>
    } & TChildProps;
export function withCharactersList<TProps, TChildProps = {}, TDataName extends string = 'data'>(operationOptions?: ApolloReactHoc.OperationOption<
  TProps,
  CharactersListQuery,
  CharactersListQueryVariables,
  CharactersListProps<TChildProps, TDataName>>) {
    return ApolloReactHoc.withQuery<TProps, CharactersListQuery, CharactersListQueryVariables, CharactersListProps<TChildProps, TDataName>>(CharactersListDocument, {
      alias: 'charactersList',
      ...operationOptions
    });
};

/**
 * __useCharactersListQuery__
 *
 * To run a query within a React component, call `useCharactersListQuery` and pass it any options that fit your needs.
 * When your component renders, `useCharactersListQuery` returns an object from Apollo Client that contains loading, error, and data properties
 * you can use to render your UI.
 *
 * @param baseOptions options that will be passed into the query, supported options are listed on: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#options;
 *
 * @example
 * const { data, loading, error } = useCharactersListQuery({
 *   variables: {
 *      name: // value for 'name'
 *   },
 * });
 */
export function useCharactersListQuery(baseOptions?: ApolloReactHooks.QueryHookOptions<CharactersListQuery, CharactersListQueryVariables>) {
        return ApolloReactHooks.useQuery<CharactersListQuery, CharactersListQueryVariables>(CharactersListDocument, baseOptions);
      }
export function useCharactersListLazyQuery(baseOptions?: ApolloReactHooks.LazyQueryHookOptions<CharactersListQuery, CharactersListQueryVariables>) {
          return ApolloReactHooks.useLazyQuery<CharactersListQuery, CharactersListQueryVariables>(CharactersListDocument, baseOptions);
        }
export type CharactersListQueryHookResult = ReturnType<typeof useCharactersListQuery>;
export type CharactersListLazyQueryHookResult = ReturnType<typeof useCharactersListLazyQuery>;
export type CharactersListQueryResult = ApolloReactCommon.QueryResult<CharactersListQuery, CharactersListQueryVariables>;
```

I don't fully understand what is the problem with types and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your type definitions you have got defined Characters response as:

```
export type Characters = {
   __typename?: 'Characters';
  info?: Maybe<Info>;
  results?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<Character>>>;
};
```

This means that even if you use the `!` command, forcing TS to believe that `data.characters!.results!` is an array and is not undefined, the Array **elements** still may be undefined (`Array<Maybe<Character>>`).

You can solve this in one of this way:

1. Make sure your API always return a valid Character, and change return type to `Array<Character>`
2. Change your `useState` definition to `useState<Maybe<Character>[]>([]);` and handle `null` characters in rendering (this seems very strange to me, but well)
3. Filter `null` characters directly in `onCompleted`

However, I think you're getting wrong the query. The `data` variable you get from the `useCharactersListQuery` destructuring, will already contains the API response, you don't need to use another local React state to store it.